# calling an object from different files

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm facing a problem when I call an object from different files.

```
function node(id, content, prev, next){
    this.id = id;
    this.prev = prev;
    this.next = next;
    this.content = content;
}
```

I'm using this code to load the external file in case if the object is not defined before.

```
function callNode(node){
    if(typeof(node) === 'undefined')
    {   
        path = "js/tree/t2.js";
        $.getScript(path, function(){
            console.log('done');
            for(i in node)
            alert(node[i]);
        });
    }
    else alert('node exist');
}
```

in the t2.js i have the following:

```
n1 = new node('text1','n1');
n2 = new node('text2','n2');
n3 = new node('text3','n3');

n2.next = n3;
n2.prev = n1;
```

the html code:

```
<button onclick="callNode(n2)"..
```

but it keeps giving me undefined object

Comment: `for(i in node)` ? `node()` looks like a function to me ?

Comment: why are you using the `new` keyword? `node()` is a function.

Comment: this how u check what are the constructors of the object

Comment: Chris, yes i did, check the code in the t2.js

Comment: I couldn't reproduce your problem. Can you provide an example on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)? On a separate note: Is it necessary to load your nodes by injecting JavaScript? Your `t2.js` could easily be replaced by loading a corresponding JSON object that provides the data for your `node()` constructor.

Comment: @adeneo: `node` is the parameter of the `callNode` function. Confusing, but OK.

Comment: @Chris: Yes, it is a function, and therefore it can be used as a constructor. Omitting the `new` would lead to ugly errors.

Comment: @T.Baba: How do you expect `n2` to be defined if only the `callNode` loads the `t2.js` script where `n2` will become initialized? Or did I miss something?

Comment: @Bergi My problem is that I need to display the content of the node n2, this n2 is initialized in the file t2.js, but this file loaded dynamically in order to save memory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot call `callNode(n2)` if `n2` is uninitialized yet. You will need to load the script first, then you can access `n2` - for example from a callback.

```
// init.js
function Node(id, content, prev, next){
    this.id = id;
    this.prev = prev;
    this.next = next;
    this.content = content;
}
var loader;
function callNode(nodeid, callback){
    if (!loader)
       loader = $.getScript("js/tree/t2.js").done(function() {
        console.log('done');
    });
    loader.done(function() {
        callback(nodes[nodeid]););
    }
}
function logNode(node) {
    // not sure whether you really want *that*, but
    for (i in node)
        alert(node[i]);
});

// t2.js
nodes = {
    n1: new Node('text1','n1'),
    n2: new Node('text2','n2'),
    n3: new Node('text3','n3')
};
nodes.n2.next = nodes.n3;
nodes.n2.prev = nodes.n1;

// event handler code:
callNode("n2", logNode);
```

Comment: what if I send the name of the object as a string, than when I load the 't2.js' I call the object ? (the function will be something like this callNode(n2, 'n2'), will test if n2 is defined or it will call the file through ajax) does it possible to do that ?

Comment: Why would you specify twice which node to call? Also, if you only test for existence of `n2` (or other variables respectively), there might even be race conditions and you would load the script twice. Have you tried my solution from above?

Comment: yea, I tried it and I put +1 but in this case I should change all my previous architect from objects to array of objects. In my suggestion, I was trying to give the fct callNode 2 parameters, the object n2 and a string 'n2', if the object n2 is not defined, can I use the string 'n2' to call the object?